# Django test to use Postgres extension without migration

Tags: django

I have an existing project that I want to start implementing test step. There are quite a few data migrations happened in the history and I don't want to spend the effort to make them run in test setup. So I have disabled 'migrations':

```py
DATABASES['default']['TEST'] = {
    'MIGRATE': False,
}
```

However this Postgres DB makes use of some extensions

```py
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'PriceBook Cache'
        verbose_name_plural = 'PriceBook Caches'
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                name="pricebookcache_gin_trgm_idx",
                fields=['itemid', 'itemdescription', 'manufacturerpartnumber', 'vendor_id'],
                opclasses=['gin_trgm_ops', 'gin_trgm_ops', 'gin_trgm_ops', 'gin_trgm_ops']
            ),
        ]
```

Which resulted error when I run the test
`psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not exist for access method "gin"`

I have had a look at here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#migration-operation-for-adding-extensions which specifically said done via migration but which I have disabled.

An alternative is using template db but I don't really want to as this will be run automatically in gitlab using docker container and I don't want to maintain another fixture outside the project repo.

So is there a way to initialise the database without running the migrations or is it possible to make it run completely different migration just for the test?

Comment: How are you creating the tables in your test db if you don't use migrations - running `migrate --run-syncdb`?

Comment: I suppose it will automatically create the tables similar to initial migration?

Comment: @IainShelvington see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES

Comment: @JamesLin Were you able to fix the issue? I am still going through same phase.